# Proverbial Soup is good for the Soul

Tags: knowledge, english

There are twenty-one(**21**) well-known, historic, **correct** English proverbs below and one(**1**) that is slightly **incorrect** when compared to the historically correct version. Astute observers will notice that exactly 22 of the words are capitalized, which deliciously coincides with the total number of proverbs.

They have been unmercifully mixed up.

There is a total of 149 words, and all should be accounted for in the correct answer.

> Your goal is to recreate the correct ones and determine what the incorrect one says.

Ready?
Set?
**GO!**

---

`a          the         wait        An          lies        A           stones`
`throw      king        and         Fortune     to          seldom      glass`
`way        All         ribcage     knowledge   the         ounce       A`
`after      and         makes       penny       a           run         things`
`apple      from        Fish        earned      through     prevention  stick`
`Speak      bedfellows  cannot      served      may         cure        carry`
`the        questions   pen         Adversity   bite        a           big`
`a          dangerous   The         A           stand       mightier    his`
`deep       together    The         flock       and         is          man's`
`feather    of          Birds       Ask         cold        never       worth`
`People     favours     live        prepared    A           who         the`
`The        tree        little      catches     three       Revenge     houses`
`is         feeds       bite        come        and         no          house`
`of         guests      those       Still       softly      waters      thing`
`to         that        early       the         is          bird        of`
`than       cat         dish        who         Don't       child       hand`
`the        is          divided     shouldn't   spoil       smell       far`
`a          hear        pound       dogs        rod         is          days`
`The        against     falls       itself      strange     look        a`
`best       you         directly    sword       is          a           Spare`
`a          at          in          Barking     no          worm        saved`
`heart      penny`

---

<sub>Perhaps a CSV version is more to your liking?</sub>

<sub>a,the,wait,An,lies,A,stones,throw,king,and,Fortune,to,seldom,glass,way,All,ribcage,knowledge,the,ounce,A,after,and,makes,penny,a,run,things,apple,from,Fish,earned,through,prevention,stick,Speak,bedfellows,cannot,served,may,cure,carry,the,questions,pen,Adversity,bite,a,big,a,dangerous,The,A,stand,mightier,his,deep,together,The,flock,and,is,man's,feather,of,Birds,Ask,cold,never,worth,People,favours,live,prepared,A,who,the,The,tree,little,catches,three,Revenge,houses,is,feeds,bite,come,and,no,house,of,guests,those,Still,softly,waters,thing,to,that,early,the,is,bird,of,than,cat,dish,who,Don't,child,hand,the,is,divided,shouldn't,spoil,smell,far,a,hear,pound,dogs,rod,is,days,The,against,falls,itself,strange,look,a,best,you,directly,sword,is,a,Spare,a,at,in,Barking,no,worm,saved,heart,penny</sub>

Comment: I take out my ELL notebook and I start to write down... other people's answers, as I know very little about English proverbs -- though I like the random proverbs forming in your lines, like "Fish earned through prevention stick speak "Bedfellows cannot served"" :D Nice puzzle!

Comment: @chowzen Are the all correct so far?

Comment: Yes, I didn't even realize it, but between the three answers, all 22 are found (including the (?) wrong one.) +1's to everyone!

Comment: Hmmm, I think I did something wrong with my map then ... Love the puzzle :D

Comment: Now I only have "directly" left. @Chowzen

Comment: That should be part of the ribcage one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I have all of the proverbs:

> Birds of a feather flock together
>  Barking dogs seldom bite
>  Revenge is a dish best served cold
>  People who live in glass houses shouldn't throw stones
>  A little knowledge is a dangerous thing
>  A penny saved is a penny earned
>  Ask no questions and hear no lies
>  Adversity makes strange bedfellows
>  An ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure
>  Fortune favors the prepared
>  A house divided against itself cannot stand
>  A cat may look at a king
>  Fish and guests smell after three days
>  The way to a man's heart is directly through his *ribcage*
>  The early bird catches the worm
>  All things come to those who wait
>  The apple never falls far from the tree
>  The pen is mightier than the sword
>  Spare the rod and spoil the child
>  Don't bite the hand that feeds you
>  Speak softly and carry a big stick
>  Still waters run deep

The wrong proverb is:

> The way to a man's heart is directly through his *ribcage*
>  It should be: The way to a man's heart is through his *stomach*

Comment: I moved the word "directly" from "king" to "ribcage." With that, this answer is complete and will get marked as accepted as soon as my loan for the pixels comes through. :)

Comment: Oh cool! This was definitely a fun puzzle!

Answer (score 5):

I have one(seven) to start it off

> The Pen is mightier than the sword.
> Birds of a feather Flock together.
>  An Ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure.
> A house divided cannot stand.
> The early bird catches the worm.
> A little Knowledge is a dangerous thing.
>  A way to a man's heart is directly through his ribcage(stomach?).

The missing one may be

> A way to a man's heart is directly through his ribcage(stomach).

Mappped with words from [practiced-liar](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69711/proverbial-soup-is-good-for-the-soul/69713#69713) and [Kevin L](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69711/proverbial-soup-is-good-for-the-soul/69715#69715)! :D

> [image]

Comment: If you're mapping (which seems like a good idea!), you should probably map one  "the" to "**T**he".

Answer (score 4):

I've got nine(?):

> Adversity makes strange bedfellows.
>  Spare the rod and spoil the child.
>  Barking dogs seldom bite.
>  Revenge is a dish best served cold.
>  Don't bite the hand that feeds you.
>  A penny saved is a penny earned.
>  Still waters run deep.
>  All things come to those who wait.
>  Fortune favours the prepared.

Comment: I always thought it was Good things come to those who wait, so maybe that's the wrong one!

Answer (score 2):

I've got 6

> A cat may look at a king
>  People who live in glass houses shouldn't throw stones
>  Speak softly and carry a big stick
>  Ask no questions and hear no lies
>  The apple never falls far from the tree
>  Fish and guests smell after three days